Embedding smooth homology sphere
Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth, $n$-dimensional homology sphere. In a paper that I am reading, the author states that there exists a smooth homotopy $n$-sphere $S$, such that the connected sum $\Sigma \# S$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.
I honestly have no idea how to approach this problem. The author says that it is not difficult to see, but all theorems that I know of (like Whitney embedding theorem) do not really look promising to me. Any help is greatly appreciated!
EDIT: The author did not specify in which dimensions this should work, but I am only interested in the case $n \geq 6$.

Would it be useful to know what paper?

@MathBug not really, it is stated as a general fact in the paper and used once and then never again...

It seems like this should follow from the argument given in this answer by @Moishe Kohan. It looks like it requires some pretty hard theorems.

@DerivedCats thank you, I skimmed over it and looks promising. I'll have to go through it carefully

The stated result is true as long as $n \neq 3$.
For $n=1$ or $2$, this follows easily from
the classification of curves and surfaces.
The case $n \geq 4$ is much harder. A proof is sketched in this answer
by Moishe Kohan.
Here I will repeat the argument with a few more details.
Everything below takes place in the smooth category.
The main ingredients

Theorem A: Let $\Sigma$ be a closed manifold of dimension $n \geq 4$.
If $\Sigma$ embeds in a homotopy sphere of dimension $n+1$,
then $\Sigma$ embeds in $S^{n+1}$.

Proof: This is a consequence of the h-cobordism theorem.
Suppose that $\Sigma$ embeds in a homotopy sphere $M$ of dimension $n+1$.
Then $\Sigma$ also embeds in the connected sum $M \# (-M)$, since
we can do the connected sum away from $\Sigma$.
By Lemma 2.4 and Lemma 2.3 of [2], $M \# (-M)$ is h-cobordant to the standard sphere $S^{n+1}$.
Since $M \#(-M)$ has dimension $n+1 \geq 5$, it follows from the h-cobordism theorem
that $M \# (-M)$ is diffeomorphic to $S^{n+1}$.
We conclude that $\Sigma$ embeds in $S^{n+1}$. $\square$

Theorem B (Kervaire [1, Theorem 3]):
Let $\Sigma$ be a homology $n$-sphere.
If $n =4$, then $\Sigma$ is the boundary of a contractible manifold.
If $n \geq 5$, then there is a homotopy $n$-sphere $X$ such
that $\Sigma \# X$ is the boundary of a contractible manifold.

Proof of the result

Proposition: Let $\Sigma$ be a homology $n$-sphere.
If $n = 4$, then $\Sigma$ embeds in $S^5$.
If $n \geq 5$, then
there is a homotopy $n$-sphere $X$ such that $\Sigma \# X$ embeds in $S^{n+1}$.

Proof: We do the case $n \geq 5$, the case $n =4$ being similar. By Theorem B, there exists a
homotopy $n$-sphere $X$ such that $\Sigma \# X$ is the boundary of a contractible manifold $V$.
Let $DV$ be the double of $V$.
Then $DV$ contains a copy of $V$, hence $\Sigma \# X$ embeds in $DV$.
Moreover, $DV$ is simply-connected by the Van-Kampen theorem and has the homology of $S^{n+1}$ by Mayer-Vietoris.
By the Whitehead theorem, it follows that $DV$ is a homotopy sphere.
By Theorem A, we conclude that $\Sigma \# X$ embeds in $S^{n+1}$. $\square$

References
[1] Kervaire, M. Smooth homology spheres and their fundamental groups. Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.144(1969), 67–72.
[2] Kervaire, M. and Milnor, J. Groups of homotopy spheres. I. Ann. of Math. (2)77(1963), 504–537.
